# Por que esse "for" com condição dupla dá loop infinito?

Tags: javascript, for

Segundo [esta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) do laço `for` no JavaScript, a segunda expressão é uma condição:

```
for ([inicialização]; [condição]; [expressão final])
   declaração
```

Se eu fizer uma condição desta forma:

```
var c = 0;
var d = 3;
for(let x = 0; x < 3 || c < d; x++){
   console.log(x);
}
```

Dá loop infinito e trava a aba do navegador (não coloquei num snippet justamento por isso).

Ora, se a condição usa o operador `||` que é "uma coisa ou outra", ou seja, o `x < 3` não deveria ser suficiente para finalizar o laço quando `x` for igual a `3` ignorando a outra condição imutável `c < d` e não dar um loop infinito? Qual seria a explicação técnica pra isso?

Comment: Não faz sentido isso. A condição é para CONTINUAR, e não para parar. OU uma OU outra continuam o loop. Sinceramente isso me parece problema de documentação básica. Inclusive, o for é irrelevante para a pergunta, esse || vai dar verdadeiro em if, while, ternário, etc. Em outras palavras, não teria razão nenhuma para ser diferente disso. Seria algo como "Se eu fizer `var x = 1`, `x` fica com valor 1. Qual a explicação técnica para isso? - R: é o comportamento esperado, não teria porque ser diferente"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O loop infinito acontece porque, nesse caso, a `[condição]` do laço `for` sempre será verdadeira.

Como `c` (`0`) *sempre* será *menor* que `d` (`3`), o segundo operando do operador OU `||` será sempre verdadeiro. Isso significa que, mesmo que eventualmente (após a terceira iteração), o primeiro operando (`x < 3`) seja avaliado como `false`, o loop continuará rodando.

Conforme consta a documentação:

> Se esta expressão for avaliada para `true`, declaração será executado.

E é exatamente o que acontece, já que:

```js
console.log(true || true); // true
console.log(false || true); // true
```